# Port messages returning to an unexpected process

Tags: elixir, erlang-ports

I have a simple ports app (literally the example from the [Erlang -- Ports documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_port.html)) and a GenServer controlling its use.

The GenServer can communicate with the C app just fine but it doesn't receive the responses, iex or its supervisor does.  If I call `flush` from iex, I see the expected message.

If I create a separate module and spawn a receive loop from it, it still doesn't receive the port response messages.

I have a feeling I'm incorrectly opening the Port but cannot prove it.  Is there anything obvious I'm screwing up?

```
port = Port.open({:spawn, "./extprg"}, [{:packet, 2}, :exit_status])
collect = fun () -> collect_results(port) end
spawn(collect)


def collect_results(port) do
   receive do
      {^port, {:data, data}} -> 
          #never gets called despite matching messages in flush
      {^port, {:exit_status, status}} ->
          #never gets called...

      {:increment, value} ->
          Port.command(port, [1, value])
          collect_results(port)
   end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When opening a port from a module that uses `GenServer`, ensure you are calling `Port.open` in the `init` function and not the `start` or `start_link` functions. `init` is ran by the new process, where `start` and `start_link` are both still the calling process.

Here is an example of a `GenServer` that uses a port:

https://github.com/fhunleth/elixir_ale/blob/master/lib/i2c.ex